# How can I increment a variable with value of another variable in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to make a grand total of the items I'm counting in a subReport. To do that, I think I need to add the value of that variable to another variable for each iteration, or "increment" it by that value. The subReport gets called for each group, and I get a total for that group. I need to add the variable values, rather than database columns/fields.

I'm receiving an integer `returnValue` from the `subReport`, which is itself the count of rows in the sub-report. I want to get the grand total, since that `subReport` is called multiple times for the different results (each for a GROUP) from my main SQL query. I want to add up all the results, but I'm getting a `null` value. I tried adding an operation to the `subReport` as a new `returnValue` and choosing `Sum` as the operation, but that also yielded a `null`.

```
   <variable name="itemCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None"/>
   <variable name="grandCount" 
      class="java.lang.Integer" 
      incrementType="Group" 
      incrementGroup="ITEM_BUNDLE">
      <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{itemCount}]]></variableExpression>
   </variable>
```

...
   <returnValue subreportVariable="countItems" toVariable="itemCount"/>

Comment: I think this question should be really simple for someone who is experienced with Jasper... no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add attribute `calculation="Sum"` to `variable name="grandCount"`

or pass `grandCount` to subreport as parameter

```
<subreportParameter name="grandCount">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{grandCount}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```

in subreport declare variable *countItems* with initialValue of parameter *grantCount*

```
<variable name="countItems" .... >
   <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{itemCount} + $P{grandCount}]]></variableExpression>
   <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{grandCount}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

and return

```
<returnValue subreportVariable="countItems" toVariable="grandCount" calculation="Sum"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I initially started down this path, but iReport gave me a bogus error whenever I added an initial value -- it said that the class of the initialValueExpression was not compatible with the class of the variable (when they were 'new Integer(0)' and 'java.lang.Integer' respectively) -- the trick was to compile the report, close it, and reopen it. I smell a bug. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly shure how to write it in JRXML since i use iReport.
In iReport, i create a new Variable, with class type "Integer", and calculation type "System"
The calculation type is important here.

In the variable expression, you will need something like $V{grandCount} = $V{grandCount} + $V{itemCount}

NOTE: JasperReports render band by band, so you wont be able to use the grandCount variable in a band before the subreport band.

Hope im not too late

Comment: Thanks for responding, medopal. The major problem is that you cannot simply add variables like <code>$V{a} = $V{a} + $V{b}</code> because $V{a} is actually a shortcut for something like <code>variable_a.value()</code> so it is read-only.
I just want to get the grand total in the report summary band at the end of the report.

The second problem is that I can't seem to initialize the variable (with <code>Initial Value Expression</code> to 0 &mdash; Not even with "new Integer(0)"

Comment: im very sure i initialize using new Integer(0) in iReport, but not sure about the $V = $V1 + $V2 though.
Anyway, i would suggest two ways:
1- Find the grand total in your sql query or back bean and pass it as parameter. I honestly never trusted how Jasper deals with the return variable.
2- In Jasper you can always link to a Java method of your own code.
Make a method with static identifier. lets say 
public static void myReportRecordCount(int i){
    staticGrandTotal+=i;
} 
call this method from the sub report details section.in the summary band, put a method to read the static variable.

Comment: Re: 1- Yes, a more complex SQL query in the main report that does what the subReport does over again might be possible, but this report already takes 5 minutes to generate, so I don't want to push it. It will make my product unusable if it takes too long to run. 
Re: 2- I'm reporting from a standard JDBC database connection, and I really want my customers to be able to use and modify the reports with iReport without having to add my custom code to their CLASSPATH.

Comment: 5 minutes? i have made few statistical reports, they were very complicated and printed on A3 papers, with 100s of pages, the query never took 5 minutes!! you might want to tune your queries.
About my first suggestion, i was suggesting something like select count(x) from table1 where group_one,group_two.... conditions. Then send this variable to the report. The select count should not make lot of overhead, its a light query.

Comment: Your assurance about 'new Integer(0)' was quite valuable. It turned out to be a flakiness/bug issue in iReport 3.6.0. As for the time required for report generation, the datasets I've been working on are quite large ( >300,000 rows with ~30 columns ) and running an a poorly tuned Microsloth SQL Server 2000 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to increment your variable (I named it totalSum) only when the band (group) is equal to the one on which the subreport is. For this you would need a field in the report to give you the current band (group).

```
<variable name="totalSum" 
         class="java.lang.Integer" 
         resetType="Report" 
         incrementType="Group" 
         incrementGroup="ITEM_BUNDLE"
         calculation="Nothing">
 <variableExpression>
 <![CDATA[new Boolean($F{reportPart}.equals("The_band_with_the_subreport")).booleanValue() ? $V{returnValue} : $V{totalSum}]]>
 </variableExpression>
 <initialValueExpression>
           <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
 </initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

I'm not sure if this works, I don't have the context to test it. But you might also try a **second solution** - with three variables. For example, you keep the value returned from the subreport (let's say **returnValue**) in a variable and you use another two variables to hold the sum - one until the subreport is called (let's say **partialSum**) and the second to store the sum between the returnValue and the partialSum. Let's call it totalSum. Then you would have something like this for totalSum:

```
<variable name="totalSum" 
         class="java.lang.Integer" 
         resetType="Report" 
         incrementType="Group" 
         incrementGroup="ITEM_BUNDLE"
         calculation="Nothing">
   <variableExpression>
        <![CDATA[$V{returnValue} +  $V{partialSum}]]>
   </variableExpression>
   <initialValueExpression>
           <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
   </initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

For  partialSum, you'll have something like this:

```
<variable name="partialSum" 
         class="java.lang.Integer"
         resetType="Report"
         calculation="Sum"
         incrementType="None">
    <variableExpression>
        <![CDATA[new Boolean($F{reportPart}.equals("The_band_with_the_subreport")).booleanValue() ? $V{returnValue} : new Integer(0)]]>
    </variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression>
         <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
    </initialValueExpression>
  </variable>
```

I hope this helps a bit. It would be easier to make all these settings from iRport directly on the report you want to use.

Comment: That's a cool idea, but not quite as straight-forward as I'd like for what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your contribution! It helped me to think about the problem differently.